# Trying to code a function with one numeric input. If the number <= 0, return -1. If the number > 0, divide that integer over-and-over by 2

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to Python and coding. This is what I have so far, but can't get it to work.

```py
def halve_to_2( num ):
    while True:
        num = num /2
        if num < 2:
            else:
                if num <=0:
                    print ("-1")
            
                return num

k = int(input("Enter a number"))
print(halve_to_2(k))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def halve_to_2( num ): 
    while True: 
        if num <= 0:
            print("-1")
            return -1
        else:
            num = num / 2


k = int(input("Enter a number")) 
print(halve_to_2(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def divisibleByTwo( num) :
        if num <=0 :
                return - 1
        else :
                divisibleByTwo (num/2)
```

Its called recursion. The break point is the return - 1 for this recursive loop

Answer (score 0):

```
def divisibleByTwo( num) :
        print ( num) 
        if int(num) > 0 :
            divisibleByTwo (num/2)
        return num/2
```

This one print the values that fall within integers not scientific decimals